# OpenGeo Suite Dashboard shows tomcat "localhost:8080" on browser instead of GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, installation, boundless-suite, windows-10

This is the first time I'm working with GeoServer. For this reason I have installed openGeoSuite 4.7.1 and Java SE 7.

The issue is that when ever I try to open the application "dashboard" (path: C:/Program Files (x86)/Boundless/OpenGeo/Dashboard ) it shows me tomcat "localhost:8080" on browser instead of GeoServer.

OS is Windows 10.

Should I change the port number?

Comment: Have you tried on this link (the default link): localhost:8080/geoserver

Comment: Have you tried to start from windows services? Recent versions of opengeo suite installed as service. Check it, and check the link above after.

Comment: @TamasKosa thank you so much i got the application interface of geosuite on browser " http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ ".

Comment: @TamasKosa thank you so much i got the application interface of geosuite on browser " http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ ". but it came after so many tries. i don't know the exactly reason but i reinstall the opengeosuite (exe file) this time i select all the options like: postGIS, GeoServer, GeoExplorer, GeoWebCache with additional GeoServer Extensions, client Tools, and Dev Tools. Numbers of times i tried to open it on browser and finally i got it.

Comment: Great to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to on this link (the default link): http://localhost:8080/geoserver

Have you tried to start from windows services? Recent versions of opengeo suite installed as service. Check it, and check the link above after

Comment: when i tried "localhost:8080/geoserver" as you are saying but it gives the error that is : HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /geoserver. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: @stackexchange please give me solution :(